# How do I pass a copy of a char* from a function instead of it's ptr's

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c-strings

I'm attempting to pass a copy of a char* from a function. However, every way I have attempted I just get a pointer to the original. Currently, I'm having to create a new char* and use strcpy_s into it I then make changes to the copy of it so it doesn't affect the original, but it feels like a very roundabout way and I was hoping there's a more direct route. Please note I wouldn't normally use char* for this. However, I've been told to use them so I haven't much choice.

Users.h (Header File)

```
class users {
public:
    users(char* username, char* password);
    ~users();

    char* getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

private:
    char* username;
    char* password;

}
```

main.cpp (function calling username)

```
bool CheckUsername(char* checkName) {

    char* username = users.getUsername();

    // my current solution...
    char* tempUser = (char*)calloc((username.size() + 1), 
    sizeof(char)); 
    //copies into temp username
    strcpy_s(username,strlen(tempUser) + 1, tempUser);

    decrypt(tempUser);

    if (strcmp(checkName, tempUser) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    delete [] tempUser;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unless you have to use `char*`'s because this is a school assignment, you should use a `std::string` instead.  That behaves just like an `int` and allows you to copy it around like a "normal" object.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: The char pointer _does_ get copied. But its _value_ is a memory address. As that does not change, the copied pointer still points to the same C-string.

Comment: If you wish to return a copy of the C-string, you need to allocate memory for that new string, use something like `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy the original into it, and return a pointer to that new chunk of memory.

Comment: @Chris I've updated it with my current solution is that the best way to go about it then? it just feels long.

Comment: @NathanOliver sadly assignment restrictions.

Comment: Where does `tempName` come from? When are you freeing the memory you allocated with `calloc`?

Comment: @chris my bad sorry I copied the wrong lines I have it in multiple places within my code

Comment: At your level of knowledge, beware copying and pasting code around. You need to be thinking about what things do, and C&P tends to lead to the opposite.

Comment: Don't use `calloc`. Don't use `char*` variables as objects (that won't even build). ***Really*** use `std::string` and other standard library facilities until later. And read much more about pointers, memory and arrays and how they all fit together.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you HAVE to use char * due to a homework assignment that specifically says, then fine. But if so, your professor is giving you bad practices.

I'm going to take your code and fix it.

Changes to class users:

- I made the arguments const where I could.
- I made your destructor virtual. This is important
- I made getUsername() return a const char *. This is just good practice.
- I marked it const.
- And I auto-initialized your variables to nullptr.

  class users {
  public:
  users(const char* username, const char* password);
  virtual ~users();

  ```
   const char* getUsername() const {
       return username;
   }
  ```

  private:
  char* username = nullptr;
  char* password = nullptr;
  }

Your constructor. I got rid of variable name shadowing. You didn't provide one, so I'm making sure. Note that I used strdup() -- which is a C function.

```
users::users(const char* theUsername, const char* thePassword) {
     username = theUsername != nullptr ? strdup(theUsername) : nullptr;
     password = thePassword != nullptr ? strdup(thePassword) : nullptr;

}
```

malloc(), cmalloc(), remalloc(), and strdup() are old-school C methods. You do not use delete[]. You use free().

```
users::~users() {
    if (username != nullptr) {
        free(username);
    }
    if (password != nullptr) {
        free(password);
    }
}
```

Now your CheckUsername. I changed the argument type to const. I also made use of const in getting the username from users. Note also you have a memory leak! See how I got rid of `return true` and use `retVal` instead.

```
bool CheckUsername(const char* checkName) {
    bool retVal = false;

    const char* username = users.getUsername();

    // my current solution...
    if (username != nullptr) {
        char * tempUser = strdup(username);

        // Are you absolutely sure this method decrypts in place and
        // consumes no extra space?
        decrypt(tempUser);

        if (strcmp(checkName, tempUser) == 0) {
            retVal = true;
        }
        free(tempUser);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Frankly, this is ugly. The code is a LOT cleaner with `std::string`. Plus it handles non-ASCII characters like foreign words.

The most important part is to match your allocation and free style. If using old-style memory management, then use old-style consistently.

Alternatively in this code you could make a `myStrdup()` method that uses `new char[]` instead of `strdup()`, and then you could use `delete []`.